# Bounce Rate for Macintosh extraordinarily high

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate

Google Analytics is reporting a bounce rate of 10.24% for Windows Operating System and 8.79% for IOS for our home page. However, for Macintosh, it's reporting a bounce rate of 42.39%!!

Looking at browsers rather than OS, I see Safari has a bounce rate of 26.5% and Chrome only has a bounce rate of 8.44%, Internet explorer has 10.59%.

What can I do to investigate this further? Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Have you actually viewed the website on each different OS? It's possible that something may not be displaying or working properly on on Mac's, and that's causing the higher bounce rate. Also, what's the size of your sample set?

Comment: We have nothing but Mac in our office so we've tested a lot. Our site gets 300,000+ visits per month.

Comment: Is everybody using Mac's in the Office using Safari? Could it be related to in-office users hitting the homepage, and then immediately going elsewhere? Ie. is your company homepage the default page when a user opens a new browser window, after which they immediately go to Google?

Comment: We use a mixture of Chrome and Safari and no, we don't go to our site on browser load. We have 300,000+ visits a month, so I'm not sure it would even make a dent! :)

Comment: it's probably a bot. refer to this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125239/i-am-tracking-my-android-app-on-google-analytics-why-do-i-appear-to-have-macint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it has to do with the preset Browser search engines i.e. IE is Bing, Chrome is Google (.com or local) but Safari can be set by the user - have a look at the 'referring domain' in the organic search results to check the bounce rates.

Comment: Its best to use the comment box for asking for additional details, as this is not an answer.

Comment: You're a bit fast off the start line there! I was editing my answer when you chipped in :-)

Comment: hehe my bad soz ;')

Comment: I can't see that in GA. I'm in Traffic Sources > Search > Organic - where is it from there?

Comment: Go to Traffic Sources > Sources > Search > Organic > set the Primary Dimension to Source and the Secondary Dimension to Browser. You can also set to Country which should be interesting too. GA won't tell you everything, but look to the trends and bounce rates for each referring country and the search engine Vs browsers etc...

Comment: You were right. Here is the answer. It's Safari's "Top Sites" feature: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/ujUzJEfcme0

Comment: Here's a fix for it: http://michaelschuck.com/high-bounce-rates-from-safari/

Comment: @Samuurai Did you implement the fix? Did it work as intended?